# GULUserDefaults crash Swift Xcode (maybe firebase)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, userdefaults

[image]I am facing this error really randomly and rarely but still want to fix it. I don't know how to reproduce it as its not happening on my device but on other users devices.
The crash log does not really help me, at least I cannot figure out where the is issue is coming from and how to solve it.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000000000001c

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19fa3513c object_isClass + 16
1  Foundation                     0x18c807978 KVO_IS_RETAINING_ALL_OBSERVERS_OF_THIS_OBJECT_IF_IT_CRASHES_AN_OBSERVER_WAS_OVERRELEASED_OR_SMASHED + 48
2  Foundation                     0x18c807774 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 288
3  Foundation                     0x18c7413f8 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _notifyObserversOfChangeFromValuesForKeys:toValuesForKeys:] + 836
4  CoreFoundation                 0x18b3cc60c -[CFPrefsSource forEachObserver:] + 336
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18b3cde3c -[CFPrefsSource _notifyObserversOfChangeFromValuesForKeys:toValuesForKeys:] + 112
6  CoreFoundation                 0x18b541b68 ___CFPrefsDeliverPendingKVONotificationsGuts_block_invoke + 428
7  CoreFoundation                 0x18b4253f0 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 28
8  CoreFoundation                 0x18b50bd94 CFBasicHashApply + 144
9  CoreFoundation                 0x18b4253ac CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 240
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18b53d748 _CFPrefsDeliverPendingKVONotificationsGuts + 300
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18b53bf44 -[_CFXPreferences _deliverPendingKVONotifications] + 96
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18b4ff194 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 432
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18b4fe720 normalizeQuintuplet + 356
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18b4fefbc -[_CFXPreferences withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 152
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18b3c1580 -[_CFXPreferences setValue:forKey:appIdentifier:container:configurationURL:] + 128
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18b53fdd8 _CFPreferencesSetAppValueWithContainerAndConfiguration + 136
17 GoogleUtilities                0x1012a7acc -[GULUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] + 109 (GULUserDefaults.m:109)
18 FirebaseMessaging              0x1011a86b0 -[FIRMessagingPubSub archivePendingTopicsList:] + 238 (FIRMessagingPubSub.m:238)
19 FirebaseMessaging              0x1011a67d4 -[FIRMessagingPendingTopicsList addOperationForTopic:withAction:completion:] + 164 (FIRMessagingPendingTopicsList.m:164)
20 FirebaseMessaging              0x1011a8304 -[FIRMessagingPubSub subscribeToTopic:handler:] + 184 (FIRMessagingPubSub.m:184)
21 FirebaseMessaging              0x1011a16a8 __44-[FIRMessaging subscribeToTopic:completion:]_block_invoke + 674 (FIRMessaging.m:674)
22 FirebaseInstanceID             0x101166674 __39-[FIRInstanceID instanceIDWithHandler:]_block_invoke + 220 (FIRInstanceID.m:220)
23 FirebaseInstanceID             0x101167ee8 __34-[FIRInstanceID getIDWithHandler:]_block_invoke + 454 (FIRInstanceID.m:454)
24 FirebaseInstallations          0x1011378a8 __49-[FIRInstallations installationIDWithCompletion:]_block_invoke + 210 (FIRInstallations.m:210)
25 FBLPromises                    0x100deda48 __56-[FBLPromise chainOnQueue:chainedFulfill:chainedReject:]_block_invoke.48 + 273 (FBLPromise.m:273)
26 libdispatch.dylib              0x18b0d324c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
27 libdispatch.dylib              0x18b0d4db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x18b0e2800 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 920
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18b45c11c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18b456120 __CFRunLoopRun + 2508
31 CoreFoundation                 0x18b45521c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
32 GraphicsServices               0x1a24d4784 GSEventRunModal + 164
33 UIKitCore                      0x18de8e200 -[UIApplication _run] + 1072
34 UIKitCore                      0x18de93a74 UIApplicationMain + 168
35 MyApp                           0x100424788 main + 20 (HashtagTableViewCell.swift:20)
36 libdyld.dylib                  0x18b1156c0 start + 4
```

It looks like its coming from firebase but ultimately it crashes on the user defaults.

Any idea or hint how to solve this is greatly appreciated.

```
GULUserDefaults.m line 109
```

this is the headline of the crash in my firebase Crashlytics

Comment: Start looking here: HashtagTableViewCell

Comment: Hey, this is always pointed out in any error code I get and I have no idea why :D this cell does only show a label. There is no saving on userdfaults done. Not lying that this cell is shown on any other error code as well. must be a mistake by xcode

Comment: What do you mean it crashes on the user defaults. Maybe show some code where you are interacting with user defaults so we could help debug. Or install Crashlytics if you are using firebase and use their dashboard to identify crashes.

Comment: I am using Crashlytics and the above shown code is the crash log from firebase I receive when it crashes on other users device. I assume its on user defaults because it says "GULUserDefaults". I edited the question, check under "edit"